# (Num a) vs Integer type inference

Tags: haskell

Consider the following Haskell function:

```
sign a
  | a < 0 = (-1)
  | a > 0 = 1
  | otherwise = 0
```

When I load this into ghci I expected `:t sign` to be:

```
sign :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Integer
```

Instead it inferred it as:

```
*Main> :t sign
sign :: (Num a1, Num a, Ord a1) => a1 -> a
```

Similarly, if I ask for the type of the integer `5`, I expected `Integer`, but instead I got

```
*Main> :t 5
5 :: Num a => a
```

There's something I am not understanding about Haskell's types. The thing is, if all I know about the return type of `sign` is that it is an instance of the `Num` typeclass, then I should not be able to pass its return value into this function:

```
double :: Integer -> Integer
double x = x * 2
```

That is, my `double` function requires an `Integer`, not just any instance of `Num`.

Yet, the following works just fine:

```
*Main> double (sign 5.5)
2
```

What is it that I am mis-understanding about Haskell's type system?

Comment: By the way, there is, of course also the function `signum :: Num a => a -> a`, i.e you pass a number into it, and get back a number *of the same type*.

Comment: The fact that you passed it to `double` gives the type inference engine more knowledge--it knows it works with `double`, and figures out how to make that possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The thing is, if all I know about the return type of 'sign' is that it is an instance of the `Num` typeclass, then I should not be able to pass its return value into this function:

Right, if that were all that you knew, you couldn't pass it to `double`.

But the type

```
sign :: (Num a1, Num a, Ord a1) => a1 -> a
```

means that the result type of `sign` is *whichever* `Num` type *the caller demands*. Type variables in type signatures are (implicitly) *universally* quantified, not *existentially*, like for e.g. Java interfaces.

`sign` can produce a return value of arbitrary type, subject to the restriction it be an instance of `Num`, and the type it returns is determined by the calling context.

If the caller wants an `Integer`, it gets one. If it wants a `Double`, no problem either.

I forgot to mention initially:

> Similarly, if I ask for the type of the integer 5, I expected "Integer", but instead I got

```
    *Main> :t 5
    5 :: Num a => a
```

Numeric literals are polymorphic, an integer literal stands for `fromInteger value`, and a fractional literal for `fromRational value`.

Comment: Somewhat. Nevertheless, let it stand, it's good to have an alternative phrasing around.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer! This explains things a little bit for me... I was forgetting that the return type is "Num a" - Num where "a" can be anything (with proviso that "Num a" type constructor exists).

Comment: @PaulHollingsworth correction, "with proviso that" there exists an {instance for [the `Num` type class](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Num)} of the [concrete type](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Integer), as which type the {type variable `a`} ends up being instantiated - simply because [the concrete method](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger) from *that instance* is what will actually be used.

Comment: @DanielFischer `"Type variables in type signatures are (implicitly) universally quantified, not existentially, like for e.g. Java interfaces."` Could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 10):

I just wanted to clarify @DanielFischer's answer a little. A type signature like `f :: Num b => a -> b` means that `f` is capable of returning *any* instance of the typeclass `Num`. When `f` is called, Haskell uses the context (the type signature of the caller) to determine the concrete type of `b`.

Moreover, Haskell's numeric literals are an example of this type of polymorphism. That's why `:t 5` gave you `Num a => a`. The symbol `5` is capable of acting as *any* type of number, not just an integer. The context it appears in determines which it will be.

Comment: To put it more precisely (but less readably): `f` is capable of returning any value whose type is an instance of `Num`. The context of the call to `f` is used to determine the concrete _type_ of `b`; the returned _value_ depends on `f` and the input data, of course.

Answer (score 7):

In Haskell, if a function returns type `x` is its result, that means that *the caller* can choose what `x` should be, not *the function*. Rather, *the function* must be able to return *any possible type*.

Your `sign` can return any type of data - including `Integer`. The `double` function wants an `Integer`, so that's just fine - `sign` can return that.

Another part of the puzzle you may not be aware of: In Java, `2` has type `int` and `2.0` has type `double`. But in Haskell, `2` has type `Num x => x` - in other words, *any possible number type*. (Also `2.0` has type `Fractional x => x`, which is a similar deal.)